# How to integrate PayPal payment with my software registration/upgrade

Tags: paypal

I want to integrate PayPal payments with my software registration/upgrade. I have my own licensing system, where license is installed locally on client endpoint and stored on my server. The license governs available features and time limitation (may be expired). The software is for Windows.

What I want to achieve is the following registration/upgrade procedure:

i) The user has feature limited or expired/going to expire license. He wants to upgrade to full-featured unlimited license

ii) The user opens my GUI, which directs him to relevant PayPal purchasing page and asks to input transaction ID in a special field by the end

iii) The user completes the PayPal processing and receives transaction ID

iv) My server automatically gets notified about transaction ID and kind of license purchased

v) The user inputs transaction ID in my GUI and clicks to complete upgrade

vi) My GUI contacts my server with the request: its local license, transaction ID and requested license

vii) If requested license and transaction ID in (vi) match the notified license and transaction ID in (iv), the server generates the requested license and sends it back to GUI, also storing it at its side

viii) The GUI updates the locally installed license - now the user has what he requested and paid for

I want the procedure to be as automated as possible, with at most one user interaction in step (v), or (yet better) without it. Is it possible to achieve it with PayPal API? My Windows GUI is a standalone executable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll essentially need a server web application that handles everything. Rather than starting from scratch, you may want to search for a 3rd party / off the shelf solution that you can configure, customize, or extend.

The PayPal API will only be relevant for payment processing. Basically setting up the redirect for step iii, and handling the return on step iv. Everything else won't really have anything to do with PayPal or payment processing, and so is general webdev and client/server app stuff